Regarding Picamera error: (Not working when button is pressed second time)
I was trying to use pi camera with buttons and at the first time is works perfectly but when i click the stop button and again try to click the start button it throws an error.
i have tried stopping the picamera by using picam2.stop , picam2.close and also tried to delete the picam2  variable but didn't got any effect
purpose of code:
i want to display the live camera in pyside label and want to take photos at regular interval(which i haven't included yet because of this issue) if some one have any other good idea how to do it please feel free to share.
my code :
from PySide6 import QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QFrame,QStatusBar,QMainWindow, QApplication, QLabel, QVBoxLayout,QPushButton,QTextBrowser,QAbstractScrollArea
from PySide6.QtGui import QPixmap,QIcon,QCursor,QFont
import sys
import cv2
from PySide6.QtCore import Signal,Slot, Qt, QThread,QRect
import numpy as np

from datetime import datetime


import time
from picamera2 import Picamera2

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = Signal(np.ndarray)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._run_flag = True

    def run(self):
        # capture from web cam
        self._run_flag = True
        self.picam2 = Picamera2()
        self.picam2.configure(self.picam2.create_preview_configuration(main={"format":"RGB888","size":(640,480)}))
        self.picam2.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        #self.cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        while self._run_flag:
            #ret, cv_img = self.cap.read()
            self.frame = self.picam2.capture_array()
            #if ret:
            self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(self.frame)
        # shut down capture system
        self.picam2.close()
        #self.picam2.stop()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows

    def stop(self):
        """Sets run flag to False and waits for thread to finish"""
        #self.picam2.close()
        self.picam2.stop()
        del self.picam2
        time.sleep(10)
        cv2.destroyAllWindows
        self._run_flag = False


class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        self.resize(1121, 581)
        icon = QIcon(QIcon.fromTheme(u"camera-video"))
        self.setWindowIcon(icon)
        self.setWindowOpacity(1.000000000000000)
        self.setToolTipDuration(-1)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")
        self.setWindowTitle('Live')
        self.initWindow()

    def initWindow(self):
        # create the video capture thread
        self.thread = VideoThread()

        # Button to start video
        self.start = QPushButton(self)
        self.start.setText("Start")
        self.start.setGeometry(QRect(210, 10, 201, 51))
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.ClickStartVideo)

        self.stopped = QPushButton(self)
        self.stopped.setText("Stop")
        self.stopped.setGeometry(QRect(680, 10, 201, 51))
        self.stopped.clicked.connect(self.ClickStopVideo)

        # Status bar
        self.status = QStatusBar()
        self.status.setStyleSheet("background : lightblue;")  # Setting style sheet to the status bar
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)  # Adding status bar to the main window
        self.status.showMessage('Ready to start')

        self.disply_width = 669
        self.display_height = 501
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setText("Press start")
        self.label.setGeometry(QRect(50, 80, 640, 480))
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        font.setBold(True)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.label.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.Box)
        self.label.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Shadow.Raised)
        self.label.setLineWidth(5)
        self.label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser(self)
        self.textBrowser.setText("Logs")
        self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QRect(710, 80, 391, 481))
        self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QFrame.Shape.WinPanel)
        self.textBrowser.setLineWidth(1)
        self.textBrowser.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarPolicy.ScrollBarAsNeeded)
        self.textBrowser.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.SizeAdjustPolicy.AdjustToContents)

    # Activates when Start
    def ClickStartVideo(self):
        # Change label color to light blue
        self.status.showMessage('Video Running...')
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()


    # Activates when Stop 
    def ClickStopVideo(self):
        
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.disconnect()
        self.status.showMessage('Ready to start')
        self.label.setText('Press start')
        VideoThread.stop(self)

    def update_image(self, cv_img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(cv_img)
        self.label.setPixmap(qt_img)

    def convert_cv_qt(self, cv_img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(cv_img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.disply_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())`
```




Expected :
was when after pressing stop button and again pressing start button the video should again start to display 

but it threw an error :

[1:30:52.630328840] [33382] ERROR Camera camera.cpp:675 Camera in Running state trying acquire() requiring state Available

Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 257, in __init__

self._open_camera()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 466, in _open_camera

self.camera.acquire()

RuntimeError: Failed to acquire camera: Device or resource busy

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/pi/Desktop/cam_system/testgui_1.py", line 25, in run

self.picam2 = Picamera2()

^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 269, in __init__

raise RuntimeError("Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.")

RuntimeError: Camera __init__ sequence did not complete.

Exception in thread Thread-6 (listen):

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner

self.run()

File "/usr/lib/python3.11/threading.py", line 975, in run

self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 90, in listen

callback()

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/picamera2.py", line 107, in handle_request

self.cameras[req.cookie]._requests += [CompletedRequest(req, self.cameras[req.cookie])]

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera2/request.py", line 108, in __init__

self.config = self.picam2.camera_config.copy()

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'

Please help


Updated code is:
